# multiple router-views for multiple routes with viewPorts

Tags: aurelia

I'm new to aurelia,
In my app.js i have two routers as shown below:

```
export class App {
 configureRouter(config, router) {
 config.title = 'Aurelia';
 config.map([ 
  { route: '', name: 'home', viewPorts: { left: { moduleId: 'home' }, 
   right: { moduleId: 'contact' }  }, title:'home' },
  { route: 'about', name: 'about', viewPorts: { center: { moduleId: 
   'about' } }, title:'about'  }
]);
this.router = router;
}[enter image description here][1]
}
```

And In app.html

```
<template>
     <div style="border: 1px solid black;">
     <router-view name="left"></router-view>
    </div>

    <br />

    <div style="border: 1px solid green;">
    <router-view name="right"></router-view>
   </div> 

   <br /> 

   <div style="border: 1px solid red;">
   <router-view name="center"></router-view>
   </div> 
</template>
```

And In output
router-view, with name left and right, shows  the  content of home and contact respectively.
But router-view with name center, doesn't show any content of about.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is because you're configuring your `center` viewPort in the `/about` route - when you're viewing the app via the `/` route. If you move the `center` viewPort config into your first route, alongside `left` and `right`, it should work.